# Android development: how to open a .dcm file as a bitmap?

Tags: android, android-image, dicom

I'm currently trying to make an android dicom app
Following code opens pictures drom res/drawable in "ussual" image formats, but it doesn't work with .dcm

```
public class BitmapView extends View
{
    public BitmapView(Context context) {
            super(context);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 10, 10, null);
    }
}
```

in the main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(new BitmapView(this));     
    }
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dicom is a kind of generic container. Inside a Dicom file you can find a huge variety of image formats. From grayscale ones to RGB, from single frame to multiframe ones, with pixel value ranges not in the ordinary 8 bit (24/32 in RGB/RGBA) but also in 12 or 16 bit grayscales.

Dicom files include many elements (fields) indicating the type of the contents and even how such contents should be [presented](https://www.clearcanvas.ca/Portals/0/ClearCanvasFiles/Documentation/DevelopersGuide/1_5_SP1/index.html?dicom_presentation_state.htm). It is not as simple as converting the Dicom image to BMP.

If you are retrieving Dicom images from a PACS, I would suggest using [WADO](http://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/projects/software/wado/) service. This way, you can obtain Jpeg images (the results of having applied a presentation state to the contents of the Dicom file).

The other option is to use some utility to convert the Dicom file to a more conventional image format. There are some excellent open source tools, such as [dcmj2pnm](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmj2pnm.html), from the [DCMTK](http://dicom.offis.de/dcmtk.php.en) toolkit.

Comment: `presented` link broken with 404 not found , Please update it to valid one

Comment: Link updated. Now it points to a different site with the same contents: The concept of DICOM Presentation State

Answer (score 1):

Dicom images are not recognized by Android and therefore you cannot open them using a BitmapFactory object.

Recently [Imebra](https://imebra.com/) has been extended with Java wrappers that call the Imebra native code and comes with a pre-built JAR so you don't have to deal with JNI compilation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the 2 options mentioned by jap1968 and Paolo, which are both good but require using some method for converting the image on a different platform then viewing it on the Android device and an internet connection, you can actually view the Dicom file itself on the Android device directly if you use a library that supports DCM and its different sub-types. One such toolkit has a free demo application on Google Play here:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=leadtools.datasetdemo