# Export Dicom images to tif format

Tags: c#, asp.net, dicom

```
using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(C:\Users\112\AppData\Local\Temp\113837.dcm))
{
    // obtain the XResolution and YResolution TIFFTAG values
    PropertyItem piXRes = bmp.GetPropertyItem(282);
    PropertyItem piYRes = bmp.GetPropertyItem(283);

    // values are stored as a rational number - numerator/denominator pair
    numerator = BitConverter.ToInt32(piXRes.Value, 0);
    denominator = BitConverter.ToInt32(piXRes.Value, 4);
    float xRes = numerator / denominator;

    numerator = BitConverter.ToInt32(piYRes.Value, 0);
    denominator = BitConverter.ToInt32(piYRes.Value, 4);
    float yRes = numerator / denominator;

    // now set the values
    byte[] numeratorBytes = new byte[4];
    byte[] denominatorBytes = new byte[4];

    numeratorBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(600); // specify resolution in numerator
    denominatorBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(1);

    Array.Copy(numeratorBytes, 0, piXRes.Value, 0, 4); // set the XResolution value
    Array.Copy(denominatorBytes, 0, piXRes.Value, 4, 4);

    Array.Copy(numeratorBytes, 0, piYRes.Value, 0, 4); // set the YResolution value
    Array.Copy(denominatorBytes, 0, piYRes.Value, 4, 4);

    bmp.SetPropertyItem(piXRes); // finally set the image property resolution
    bmp.SetPropertyItem(piYRes);

    bmp.SetResolution(600, 600); // now set the bitmap resolution

    bmp.Save(@"C:\output.tif"); // save the image
}
```

I'm getting an "Out of memory" error on the line `using (Bitmap bmp = ...`. How can I solve that?

Comment: I think the first, and most incredibly obvious question is, "How big is `Temp\113837.dcm`?"

Comment: it may be any size, 7 kb to 100 mb

Answer (score 2):

The "out of memory" is misleading.  It really means that the image format can not be determined by .Net.

Sorry but .Net does not support DICOM images.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx for info on supported image formats.

Comment: Ah, that's right. I always forget about this weird errno translation issue. Good catch.

Comment: Too true. In my day job I deal with DICOM images all the time and knew that .Net doesn't support them.

Answer (score 2):

With this line...

```
(Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(C:\Users\112\AppData\Local\Temp\113837.dcm)
```

...you are reading the whole raw data contained in a dicom file. That includes the Dicom Data Elements (fields containing information).

Extracting the image data is [much more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16325123/176974) than this. You should begin looking for some information about [the Dicom format](http://medical.nema.org/standard.html).

Other good sources of information to start can be found on [Dabsoft](http://www.dabsoft.ch/dicom/) and [Medical Connections](http://www.medicalconnections.co.uk/list-of-kb-articles) and, of course, on the David Clunie's [website](http://www.dclunie.com/).